# What is the pdf of sum of two complex non-zero Gaussian random variable $(x,y)$ and one Gassian mixture random variable $w$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I have three complex random variable $x,y,w$.

The pdf of $x$ is ${f_x} \sim CN({\mu _x},\sigma _x^2)$ with mean ${\mu _x}$ and variance $\sigma _x^2$.

The pdf of $y$ is ${f_y} \sim CN({\mu _y},\sigma _y^2)$ with mean ${\mu _y}$ and variance $\sigma _y^2$.

The random variable $w$ is a mixture of $M$ Gaussian component with corresponding mean  ${{\mu _{w,i}}}$ and variance ${\sigma _{w,i}^2}$ where,

${f_w} \sim \sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i}CN({\mu _{w,i}},\sigma _{w,i}^2)} $

where $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {{\varepsilon _i} = 1} $

Now, for a constant $a,b,c\in R$

$z=ax+by+cw$,

What will be the pdf of  $f_z$? How should I express the mean ${\mu _z}$ and variance $\sigma _z^2$? Thank you.

Comment: Where does convexity enter into all of this?

Comment: $f_w$ is a Gaussian mixture which is a combination of M Gaussian. I thought this might be convex? I think I am wrong. Thank you.